# Laravel5.5 adding columns to a collection from a second one

Tags: laravel, collections

I have a sql request concerning admin :

```
$admin = Admin::findOrFail(Auth::guard('admin')->user()->id);
```

from this sql request I also manage to get the users of the admin ...

```
$users = $admin->users;
```

Each users must follow training sessions. and I must calculate it by using SQL requests for each users ... So i wrote this foreach statement

```
foreach ($users as $user) {
    $todo = User::select() .....where('users.id' = $user->id)->get();
    $done = User::select() .....where('users.id' = $user->id)->get();

    $totalTimes = $todo->toBase()->sum('dureeformation');
    $spendTimes = $done->toBase()->sum('dureeformation');
    $remainingTimes = $totalTimes - $spendTimes;

    $timeData[] = ['id' => $user->id, 'totalTime' => $totalTimes, 'spendTime' => $spendTimes, 'remainingTime' => $remainingTimes];
}
```

the totalTimes, spendTimes and remainingTimes are operations on Collections and i get expected results ...

```
$users->each(function ($record) use ($timeData) {
    $record['totalTime'] = $timeData[$record['id']]['totalTime'];
    $record['spendTime'] = $timeData[$record['id']]['spendTime'];
    $record['remainingTime'] = $timeData[$record['id']]['remainingTime'];
    //dd($record['totalTime']);


});
```

After this :

```
$timeData = collect($timeData);
$timeData= $timeData->keyBy('id');
$users = collect($users->toArray());
```

I have an issue here :

```
$users->each(function ($record) use ($timeData) {
    $record['totalTime'] = $timeData[$record['id']]['totalTime'];
    $record['spendTime'] = $timeData[$record['id']]['spendTime'];
    $record['remainingTime'] = $timeData[$record['id']]['remainingTime'];
    //var_dump($record);
});
```

$record in the function gives me what i expect ... the var_dump($records) added columns where it was expected but i can't take those results out of the function.

I tried to do this :

```
$variable = $users->each(function ($record) use ($timeData)... 
dd($variable)
```

but unsuccessfully ...

Answer (score 0):

Looks to me like your `$timeData` array is built differently than you access it. In your code you are doing

```
$timeData[] = [
    'id' => $user->id,
    'totalTime' => $totalTimes,
    'spendTime' => $spendTimes,
    'remainingTime' => $remainingTimes,
];
```

which will produce an array like this

```
[
    0 => [
        'id' => 17,
        'totalTime' => 5,
        'spendTime' => 4,
        'remainingTime' => 3
    ],
    1 => [
        'id' => 17,
        'totalTime' => 7,
        'spendTime' => 5,
        'remainingTime' => 2
    ]
]
```

but what you actually want is to have the `id` as index, right? Then you'd have to build the array this way:

```
$timeData[$user->id] = [
    'totalTime' => $totalTimes,
    'spendTime' => $spendTimes,
    'remainingTime' => $remainingTimes,
];
```

or, as an alternative, perform a different lookup:

```
$users->each(function ($record) use ($timeData) {
    $times = array_first($timeData, function ($value, $key) use ($record) {
        return $value['id'] === $record['id'];
    });
    $record['totalTime'] = $times['totalTime'];
    $record['spendTime'] = $times['spendTime'];
    $record['remainingTime'] = $times['remainingTime'];
});
```

Both solutions have pros and cons, though. On the one hand, using the user identifier as the index will produce a huge array that is only filled partially. On the other hand, the second solution is a bit slower. As long as you are not going to deal with thousands of entries in the `$timeData` array, this won't be an issue, though.

Comment: my timeData was not at the right place ... i'm going to try your solution tomorrow :)